# How do I access the title of an iTunes song using MLMediaLibrary and Swift on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, itunes, media-library

I'm using Apple's MediaLibrary framework on macOS, to write an application that reads in information on every song in my iTunes library.

I'm able to extract the artist of a song, using `MLMediaObjectArtistKey` as a key in the `attributes` dictionary (property on `MLMediaObject`), but how do I access the *title* of the song?

From what I can tell from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/medialibrary/1980254-medialibrary_constants/1658694-media_object_attribute_keys), it seems that this information (the title) simply is not provided through the `attributes` dictionary.

Have others had any luck retrieving the title, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a **MLMediaObject**:

- you can use the `.name` attribute:

> ```
> print("\(mediaObj.attributes[MLMediaObjectArtistKey]!), \(mediaObj.name!)") // Swift
> ```

- Or you can use the "**Name**" key from a dictionary object:

> `mediaObj.attributes["Name"]`

---

To get the keys from a dictionary:

```
print(Array(mediaObj.attributes.keys)) // Swift
```